# Assigning private to the certificate object fails (CryptographicException: Access is denied.)

Tags: c#, cryptography, signing, cryptoapi

I am using CmsSigner class to sign data. I am using a certificate with HSM provider hence, I am trying to set CspParameter to teach my code what provider it should use.

```
            X509Certificate2 cert = GetCertificate("Signer cert");
        ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(FileToSign);

        CspParameters csp = new CspParameters()
        {
            ProviderName = "nCipher RSA AES provider",
            ProviderType = 1,
            KeyNumber = (int)KeyNumber.Signature,
            Flags = CspProviderFlags.NoPrompt | CspProviderFlags.UseExistingKey | CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore,
            KeyContainerName = "myContainer"
        };

        RSACryptoServiceProvider priKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(csp);
        cert.PrivateKey = priKey;
        CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(cert);
        signer.DigestAlgorithm = new Oid("2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1");
        signer.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.EndCertOnly;
        signer.SignedAttributes.Add(new Pkcs9SigningTime(DateTime.UtcNow));
        signedCms = new SignedCms(content, true);
        signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer);
```

The RSACryptoServiceProvider instantiation (RSACryptoServiceProvider priKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(csp);) is now fixed with the additional flags. However the next line cert.PrivateKey = priKey fails with Access denied error.

Is there an obvious issue with my code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329955/rsacryptoserviceproviderrsacryptoserviceprovider-constructor-crashing-in-net might help

Comment: a) isn't the correct provider name `"nCipher Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider"`?  b) maybe it was saved under KeyNumber.Exchange?  c) Do you have the right key container name?

Comment: I have replaced provider name and key container name with dummy values for this post. I am pretty sure it's KeyNumber.Signature. The container name is correct as well.

Comment: The only things that produce the exception are a) bad provider name, b) bad key name, c) wrong key number, d) wrong provider type, e) needing CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKey (or needing to not use it).  "d" looks right, or maybe it needs to be 24.  If "a" and "b" are right then try toggling "c". If you've done that, toggle "e", then toggle "c" back and forth.   If the provider only responds to CNG then you need to do different things.  But without knowing (at least) the correct name of the provider, this is the end of the advice I can give.

Comment: @Mrdoxx comment helped to get rid of error instantiating the class but now I get issue with assigning private key value. I have updated the question. Any idea?